# Where are Nuget packages stored on Azure DevOps 2019

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We installed Azure DevOps 2019 on a server in our company. The uploaded Nuget packages are stored in the Artifacts part of Azure Devops. Since we like to keep our code locally on our servers we would like to know where the uploaded nuget package files are stored. Are they only stored on the local company server or are the nuget files uploaded to the Azure cloud? If they are uploaded to the Azure cloud is there a way to upload them only to our own server?

Comment: Do you mean you want to access the nuget packages in the Azure Devops Artifacts? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/where-is-package-management?view=vsts. Is there any limit you can't access or you don't know how to use nuget package in the Artifacts? Give more info, so that we could to know clear what you want to do.

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT thanks for your reply. I want to know where the nuget files are stored. Are they located somewhere on the harddrive or are they stored into the database? What happends when I upload a nuget file does it remain within my organization network or is stored somewhere on a nuget server in the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to access my nuget packages files that I upload using the DevOps 2019 NuGet Package Manager?

NuGet packages are stored in the Artifacts of Azure Devops, which located in the Azure Devops server(cloud server). When you upload a nuget file, file will be stored into the zure Devops server. But you could still see it from Azure Devops site:

[image]

You could download the nuget package and you can also access the nuget package from Visual Studio, Azure Devops, nuget CLI, etc.

Check the document [Get started with NuGet packages in Azure DevOps Services and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azdevops&tabs=new-nav) for some more details.

If I understand you incorrect, please let me know for free, I will keep follow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify we installed the Azure Devops 2019 Server on our organization premise. So when I upload a nuget package is it only stored localy on that server or is it stored in the Azure cloud outside the organization?

Comment: @doorman, In that case, it only only stored local on that server.

Comment: Thanks, in any case I rephrased the question if you would like to reopen it.

Comment: I have the same question. Is it stored in the collection sql database tables? Is it stored on Azure DevOps server host file system? How can I configure the location on the same server or any other server?

Comment: Packages in on-premises Azure DevOps Server are stored in the database. No configuration is available.